# Parabolic point geometric interpretation

Tags: geometry, surfaces

I know the definition of a parabolic point, but I can't find a surface in which each point is a parabolic point. Any examples? (I mean, for example all of the points of an hyperbolic paraboloid are hyperbolic points, so which surface has all of its points as parabolic points?)

Comment: What definition of parabolic point are you working from? It would seem to me that a cylinder would be such an example: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParabolicPoint.html

Comment: Yes, the link definition is what I'm using

Comment: Then the cylinder ($S^1\times \Bbb{R}$) is an example.